# How to inject variables from a file in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a text file :

```
export URL = "useful url"
export NAME = "some name"
```

What I do is executing this file with command `source var_file.txt` 
But when I do `echo $URL` or `env.URL` it returns nothing.

Please I don't have the ability to change the file var_file.txt : it means it will still be `export var= value var`

I know that it is possible to use `load file.groovy` step in pipeline to load variables but the file must be a list of : `env.URL = 'url'`, I can't use this because I can't change file.

And we may also work with `withEnv([URL = 'url'])` but I must first get the values from an other script. This will really be a complicated solution.

So is there a way to use the file with list of `export var = var_value` in Jenkins Pipeline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done is :

```
def varsFile = "var_file.txt"
def content = readFile varsFile
```

Get content line by line and split change the each line of content to `env.variable = value`:

```
def lines = content.split("\n")
for(l in lines){
        String variable = "${l.split(" ")[1].split("=")[0]}"
        String value = l.split(" ")[1].split("=")[1]
        sh ("echo env.$variable = \\\"$value\\\" >> var_to_exp.groovy") 
 }
```

And then load file groovy with step load in the pipeline:

```
load var_to_exp.groovy
```

Comment: I made double quotes on values because otherwise Jenkins will make this exception groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property xx. Also the >> is treated if it is the first item: > otherwise >>

Answer (score -1):

Alternative suggestion: embed scripted pipeline (not sure if there is a genuine "declarative" way of doing this -- at least I haven't found it so far):

```
stage('MyStage') {
  steps {
    script {
       <extract your variables using some Groovy>
       env.myvar = 'myvalue'
    }
    echo env.myvar
  }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how much modification you are allowed to do on your input (e.g. get rid of the `export` etc.), or whether that has to remain an executable shell script.